# units+gcd in a PID

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains

In a PID $R$ with $ a\in R $ irreducible and $\langle a \rangle$ the ideal generated by $a$, and $b \in R\setminus \langle a \rangle$,   is $1\in \gcd(a,b)$.

Why is it sufficient to show that $g \in \gcd(a,b)$ is a unit in R to show the above?

Comment: If $x$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$ and $u$ is a unit, then $ux$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$

Comment: Is $\gcd(a,b)$ an element, or is it set of elements (and if so, what set)? Because otherwise $1\in\gcd(a,b)$ does not make sense.

Comment: its the set of greatest common divisors